# Develop and implement MDM technology for parent Control app

Tags: ios, parent-child, mdm, ota, ios-enterprise

I have gone through various MDM documents given by apple and third party, like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/1-Introduction/Introduction.html) and like [this](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf).

After reading all of this and many other documents what I have found are, you need to Enterprise account for develop MDM certificate and MDM server.

Firstly you need to send device token to MDM server, so it can push profile through APNS but how?

So anyone can help with exact technical flow for installation of profile over the air, and how can control other app by push user settings??
Some kind of demo or tutorial for iOS will be helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

Resources for homegrown Apple MDM solutions are a bit sparse. The following may help steer you in the right direction:

- [Workflow for device enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH3-SW1)
- [Good overview of MDM here](http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/ior07301dd60)
- [MDM API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html)

That first link is the one you want to review for what info to send where and when for enrolling a device. The appendix includes some code samples.